# Character Width of Number Values in TSQL?

Tags: sql-server, datetime, char, casting

MSSSQL 2008.

I have 3 Ints, 1 BigInt, 1 Float, and 1 DateTime value.
I am trying to concatenate them all into a single Char value and not lose any precision, which should let me create a single unique long value.

What are would the total character width be if I could make all of the numbers Chars and then combine them? The DateTime should go to MMDDYYHHMMSS.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

INTs can be up to 10 digits.
BIGINTs can be up to 19 digits.
Floats could be anything.  They have 38 digits of precision, but could be an enormous number with limited precision (1.79E + 308).  You don't want that as a string.  If your application has knowledge of what the actual range of values the float could be, you could make an application decision for a specific number of digits.